# SQLite does not save string made of zeroes

Tags: sqlite

I'm using SQLite 3.7.4 (within my c++ app under Ubuntu PP) and when I try to save string like "000000" it saves just one char "0". I tried it in console too - is it feature, or bug? How can I get rid of that?

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE status (readTime INTEGER, status STRING);
INSERT INTO status (readTime, status) values(1234, "000000");
INSERT INTO status (readTime, status) values(4321, "111111");
SELECT * FROM status;
1234|0
4321|111111
```

Comment: [Repro](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!5/43014/1)

Comment: "STRING" isn't a SQLite data type.  Try "TEXT".

Comment: @HotLicks - Weird, does SQLLite play "guess the data type" if you put in an invalid data type in the schema or something?

Comment: See [here](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html).  (When all else fails, read the documentation.)

Comment: OH MY!!! I'm blind! Thanks, that was it! (looks like I need a vacation and you add your comment as answer so I can mark it answered)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"STRING" isn't a SQLite data type. Try "TEXT".

Answer (score 2):

Some quick research points to the fact that `STRING` is not a recognized type in SQLite (or, I believe, most other SQL dialects). However, SQLite isn't strict with its types, so the type defaulted to `NUMERIC`. You should be able to change the column type to `TEXT` to resolve your issue.

Further reading: [Type Affinity](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#affinity)

Comment: it seems you had the answer a while ago in the comments, I should refresh more often :)